# Trying to capture data while in a recursive function

Tags: python

I'm working on a personal project to try and help me learn and understand python better.  Presently, I have a decent sized nested dictionary and the information is updating correctly to it.  So what I'm attempting to do is, while I'm going through the nested dictionary, I'm trying to capture all the key, values that have been updated from the previous process.  That means that the values are either 0 or higher than that.

Here are some snippets of the "test area" I've been playing with the data in.
This is the class structure that I've been using.  The nested dictionary is self.skills.

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self):
        self.characteristics = {'STR': 0, 'DEX': 0, 'END': 0, 'INT': 0, 'EDU': 0, 'SOC': 0}
        self.other_characteristics = {'MOR': 0, 'LUCK': 0, 'SAN': 0, 'CHA': 0, 'PSI': 0, 'OTHER': 0}
        self.first_name = ''
        self.last_name = ''
        self.age = 18
        self.species = ''
        self.gender = ''
        self.home_world = ''
        self.traits = []
        self.allies = []
        self.contacts = []
        self.rivals = []
        self.enemies = []
        self.pension = ''
        self.debt = ''
        self.honors = False
        self.graduated = False
        self.survival_roll = ''
        self.advancement_roll = ''
        self.pre_career_tries = 0
        self.career_rank = -1
        self.life_terms = {}
        self.dice_modifier = {'STR': 0, 'DEX': 0, 'END': 0, 'INT': 0, 'EDU': 0, 'SOC': 0}
        self.other_dice_modifier = {'MOR': 0, 'LUCK': 0, 'SAN': 0, 'CHA': 0, 'PSI': 0, 'OTHER': 0}
        self.events = []
        self.title = ''
        self.career = 'hippo'
        self.skills = {'Admin': -1, 'Advocate': -1, 'Animals': {'Handling': -1, 'Veterinary': -1, 'Training': -1},
                       'Art': {'Performer': -1, 'Holography': -1, 'Instrument': -1, 'Visual Media': -1, 'Write': -1},
                       'Astrogation': -1, 'Athletics': {'Dexterity': -1, 'Endurance': -1, 'Strength': -1},
                       'Broker': -1, 'Carouse': -1, 'Deception': -1, 'Diplomat': -1,
                       'Drive': {'Hovercraft': -1, 'Mole': -1, 'Track': -1, 'Walker': -1, 'Wheel': -1},
                       'Electronics': {'Comms': -1, 'Computers': -1, 'Remote Ops': -1, 'Sensors': -1},
                       'Engineer': {'M-drive': -1, 'J-drive': -1, 'Life Support': -1, 'Power': -1},
                       'Explosives': -1,
                       'Flyer': {'Airship': -1, 'Grav': -1, 'Ornithopter': -1, 'Rotor': -1, 'Wing': -1}, 'Gambler': -1,
                       'Gunner': {'Turret': -1, 'Ortillery': -1, 'Screen': -1, 'Capital': -1},
                       'Gun Combat': {'Archaic': -1, 'Energy': -1, 'Slug': -1},
                       'Heavy Weapons': {'Artillery': -1, 'Portable': -1, 'Vehicle': -1}, 'Investigate': -1,
                       'Jack-of-All-Trades': -1,
                       'Language': {'Galanglic': -1, 'Vilani': -1, 'Zdetl': -1, 'Oynprith': -1, 'Trokh': -1,
                                    'Gvegh': -1}, 'Leadership': -1, 'Mechanic': -1, 'Medic': -1,
                       'Melee': {'Unarmed': -1, 'Blade': -1, 'Bludgeon': -1, 'Natural': -1}, 'Navigation': -1,
                       'Persuade': -1, 'Pilot': {'Small Craft': -1, 'Spacecraft': -1, 'Capital Ships': -1},
                       'Profession': {'Belter': -1, 'Biologicals': -1, 'Civil Engineering': -1, 'Construction': -1,
                                      'Hydroponics': -1, 'Polymers': -1}, 'Recon': -1,
                       'Science': {'Archaeology': -1, 'Astronomy': -1, 'Biology': -1, 'Chemistry': -1, 'Cosmology': -1,
                                   'Cybernetics': -1, 'Economics': -1, 'Genetics': -1, 'History': -1, 'Linguistics': -1,
                                   'Philosophy': -1, 'Physics': -1, 'Planetology': -1, 'Psionicology': -1,
                                   'Psychology': -1, 'Robotics': -1, 'Sophontology': -1, 'Xenology': -1},
                       'Seafarer': {'Ocean Ships': -1, 'Personal': -1, 'Sail': -1, 'Submarine': -1}, 'Stealth': -1,
                       'Steward': -1, 'Streetwise': -1, 'Survival': -1, 'Tactics': {'Military': -1, 'Naval': -1},
                       'Vacc Suit': -1}
```

Here is the list of skills that I'm pushing off to another function called assign_all_skills.  This portion is working correctly.  It's the portion afterwards that I'm having issues with.

```
skill = [['Admin'], ['Animals'], ['Art'], ['Athletics'], ['Carouse'], ['Drive'], ['Electronics'], ['Flyer'],
         ['Language'], ['Mechanic'], ['Medic'], ['Profession'], ['Science'], ['Seafarer'], ['Streetwise'], ['Survival'],
         ['Vacc Suit']]

choice = input('Would you like to do the next thing?  ').lower()
if choice[0] == 'y':
    mil.display()
    assign_skills.assign_all_skills(mil, skill)
    acquired_skills = dict_walk(mil.skills)
    print(f'{acquired_skills}')
```

Here is the recursive function that I put together from the research that I've done.  It prints out correctly and shows all the information the way that I want it, now.

```
def dict_walk(d):
    test = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        if type(v) == dict:
            print(k)
            dict_walk(v)
        if type(v) == int and v >= 0:
            print(k, v)
            test.append([k, v])
        else:
            continue

    return test
```

BLUF:  What I'm trying to do is have a comprehensive list that I can display to the user showing what skills they have selected(key), what rank they have been updated too(value) and  printed out in a way that isn't offensive to the eyes (currently what I'm working on).

Here is the print out that I get at the end.  The individual lines are what's produced from the recursive function.  The list of lists at the end, that's supposed to be all of the entries above that have a key, value pair that meets the criteria for printing.

```
Admin 0
Animals
Handling 0
Art
Holography 0
Athletics
Strength 0
Carouse 0
Drive
Hovercraft 0
Electronics
Computers 0
Engineer
Flyer
Ornithopter 0
Gunner
Gun Combat
Heavy Weapons
Language
Galanglic 0
Mechanic 0
Medic 0
Melee
Pilot
Profession
Biologicals 0
Science
Biology 0
Seafarer
Ocean Ships 0
Streetwise 0
Survival 0
Tactics
Vacc Suit 0
[['Admin', 0], ['Handling', 0], ['Holography', 0], ['Strength', 0], ['Carouse', 0], ['Hovercraft', 0], ['Computers', 0], ['Ornithopter', 0], ['Galanglic', 0], ['Mechanic', 0], ['Medic', 0], ['Biologicals', 0], ['Biology', 0], ['Ocean Ships', 0], ['Streetwise', 0], ['Survival', 0], ['Vacc Suit', 0]]
```

My question now is, what I have now is a super long list of items that I want to print out aesthetically pleasing.  It's going to be a dynamic list, so it could be 10 entries long, it could be 27.  Is there a way to break a list up uniformly to print it out neatly instead of just printing off of the screen?  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're creating a new list on every recursive call, not appending them all to the same list.

Comment: Since it's a function, would there be a way that I can maintain that list no matter the cycle it's on?  I thought that's what I was doing by keeping it outside the for loop, but what you're saying makes sense.  Is there a way to append the printed stuff instead?

Comment: You could pass the list as an argument to the function, and then pass it along in each recursive call.

Comment: What do you mean " break a list up uniformly"? You mean split it into sublists, and print each sublist one by one?

Comment: Yes.  I believe so.  Is there a method to do that or would that mean I would need to build a function to do so?